# using angular service to make $http calls

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a $http call from angular  service and it doesn't seem to get reflected in the html

```
var heroSliderApp = angular.module('heroSliderApp', []);

heroSliderApp.service('heroService', function ($http) {
    this.loadSlider = function () {
        $http.get("some url that returns data")
            .then(function (response) {
                return JSON.stringify(response.data);
                //return "Hello World!"; //this doesn't work
            });
    };
});

heroSliderApp.controller('heroSliderController', function ($scope, $http, heroService) {
    $scope.sliderValue = heroService.loadSlider(); // this doesn't work
    $scope.someValue= "Testing"; //this works
});
```

Here the .then function gets called and response.data contains value, but the value is not getting reflected in the html

Comment: Did you verify that your service succeeds ? .then() is not called if $http.get fails.

Comment: yeah I get value in response.data as well.

Comment: Your service doesn't return anything to your controller, so $scope.sliderValue is undefined.You need to **return** the promise from the service: `return $http.get...`, and you need to **use** the returned promise in the controller: `heroService.loadSlider().then(...)`. Why are you stringifying the object stored in the data of the response?

Comment: I was just playing around. I thought the value is not getting displayed since response.data is an object and hence tried stringify. Anyway returning $http.get works :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  this.loadSlider = function () {
      return $http.get("some url that returns data")
            .then(function (response) {
                return JSON.stringify(response.data);
                //return "Hello World!"; //even this doesn't work!
            });
    };

  heroService.loadSlider ().then(function(d) {
    $scope.sliderValue = d;
  });
```

Comment: Again, that will throw. The service needs to **return** the promise.

Comment: try it now  and let me now

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I modified according to the comments from @JB Nizet and it seem to work

```
var heroSliderApp = angular.module('heroSliderApp', []);

heroSliderApp.service('heroService', function ($http) {
    this.loadSlider = function () {
        return $http.get("some url here");
    };
});

heroSliderApp.controller('heroSliderController', function ($scope, $http, heroService) {
    $scope.sliderValue = "";
    heroService.loadSlider().then(function (response) {
        $scope.sliderValue = response;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your service like

```
heroSliderApp.service('heroService', function ($http) {
    this.loadSlider = function () {
        $http.get("some url that returns data")
            .success(function (response) {
                return JSON.stringify(response.data);
                //return "Hello World!"; //even this doesn't work!
            }).error(function {
                 //Erro handler
            });
    };
});
```

and controller like

```
heroService.loadSlider().then(function(response) {
   $scope.sliderValue = response;
})
```

Now the service will return a promise and the controller will receive it. When the controller data receives the response from service, the data will be binded in your controller variable.

Comment: Again, that will throw. You may not call then() on undefined. The service must **return** a promise. success() and error() are deprecated since 1.4, and don't exist in 1.6.